# Why can I call contract methods containing a selfdestruct multiple times?

Tags: contract-development, contract-design, evm, yellow-paper, selfdestruct

The following code is part of a Smart Contract I'm working with:

```
[...]
   function noComplain() allowed(receiver, stage.keyRevealed) public {
        selfdestruct(sender);
    }

    // function complain about wrong hash of file
    function complainAboutRoot(bytes32 _Zm, bytes32[depth] memory _proofZm) allowed(receiver, stage.keyRevealed) public {
        require (vrfy(2 * (n - 1), _Zm, _proofZm));
        require (cryptSmall(2 * (n - 1), _Zm) != fileRoot);
        selfdestruct(receiver);
    }
[...]
```

As you can see, there are multiple contract methods calling `selfdestruct`. I would expect that only a single call to e.g. `noComplain` would be allowed, since the the contract should be destroyed after that (yeah, I know, the code is still there, but the state should be lost etc, right?).

When working with the contract, I discovered that I can call `complainAbouRoot` after `noComplain`, also vice versa and even `noComplain` multiple times without getting an error (tx receipt says "status=1").

How can that be? How can I discover if a smart contract has been destroyed? What is selfdestruct actually good for if it doesn't block further calls?

Comment: I was testing a simplified version of this in Remix and seems that subsequent transactions succeed even if the contract has been self-destroyed - the transactions just don't do anything. You can see this by adding events and see that they don't get emitted after the contract has been destroyed. I'm really not sure why the subsequent transactions succeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Laurie mentioned, the effect of `selfdestruct()` is that it creates a void. Users and contracts may *think* there is a contract there (because there was) and they may *assume* that success means the functions worked as expected, but ...

As you have discovered on your own, calling the non-existent function in the non-existent contract returns `true` because there is nothing to do. I would discourage the use of `selfdestruct` because there are better patterns in almost all cases.

Have a look at this explainer: https://blog.b9lab.com/selfdestruct-is-a-bug-9c312d1bb2a5

Hope it helps.